# USD destroyed in a fire

Tags: united-states, currency, usd-us-dollar

After seeing some cash destroyed in a fire in a popular Netflix TV series, I wondered what would happen if someone's cash was destroyed in a fire.

Assuming you had some way to prove that the money was utterly destroyed, would the [U.S. Bureau of Engraving and Printing](http://www.moneyfactory.gov/) replace it?

Answer (score 16):

Hypothetically, yes!

From the U.S. BEP's guidelines on [Damaged Currency](http://www.moneyfactory.gov/uscurrency/damagedcurrency.html):

> Under regulations issued by the Department of the Treasury, mutilated
>   United States currency may be exchanged at face value if:
>
> - More than 50% of a note identifiable as United States currency is
>     present; or,
> - **50% or less of a note identifiable as United States
>     currency is present, and the method of mutilation and supporting
>     evidence demonstrates to the satisfaction of the Treasury that the
>     missing portions have been totally destroyed.**

"50% or less" includes "0%".

However, it is probably going to be very difficult to prove that the currency existed, had a specific face value, and was completely destroyed (instead of being replaced with a decoy at the last minute.)

Comment: This only talks about "mutilated" bills, nothing about charred ones.

Comment: In the photo on the BEP page, one of the three examples of mutilated currency is "burned currency".

Comment: The page only talks about "**partially** destroyed" or "badly damaged", and it says many things that require some remnant of the currency to exist.

Comment: In particular, I wouldn't be surprised if the BEP told you that regardless of whether or not 0% counts for those conditions, you still don't have any mutilated currency to exchange, so you can't exchange it. It's vague enough that someone with the resources of a big business behind them might be able to get it done, though.

Comment: So in theory, I could cut a bank note in 2, burn those places that indicate that they're actually of the same note, then turn them in and claim that they're different notes? Could this actually work, or are the indicators so spread-out that it's impossible to destroy them all?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs I have the same question too, what a coincidence ;)

Comment: I'm going to ask that as a new question, unless you already did of course.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: It seems pretty clear to me that the regulations aim to prevent exactly that case through the "easy exchange only if 50%+ of the note is present, otherwise you have to convince us with really good evidence" clause.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs You could try, but you would be committing fraud.

Comment: If you have 0% of a note, how is it `identifiable as United States currency`?

Comment: Whatever you have must be identifiable as United States currency. That's impossible with 0%.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Although a simplistic approach to solving your problem, this is why the serial number on each bill is printed on the left, and right sides of the note. Unrelated, I would assume that these rules are intended to protect consumer banks.  If a van loaded with $100 bills came straight from the Fed, drove into a bank's distribution center, which then caught on fire and burnt every bill in the place then I have no doubt that the Fed would help recover the lost currency. However, I wouldn't expect the same treatment if I lost $100k I stuffed in my mattress and lost due to a house fire.

Comment: @Rawling If your note is destroyed, `50% or less of a note identifiable as United States currency is present` because 0% is less than 50%.

Comment: @JacobKrall If you have nothing, how is it `identifiable as United States currency`?

Comment: @JacobKrall Here's this pile of ashes, I swear it was a stack of 100 dollar bills and not my deceased grandmother's ashes.

Comment: @Rawling There are many ways you could prove the existence of something after it has ceased to exist. For example, you could completely burn $100 while recording a video, seal the ashes in a serialized, tamper-proof box, and send the box and video directly to USBEP.

Comment: @SunWKim: your understanding is incorrect. Read the guidelines again.

Comment: @JacobKrall Well done, you just commited a crime, WITH evidence. Defacing money is a crime punishable by a 100 dollar fine and/or 6 months in prison. and you won't get your money back because it's evidence. The only way this will work is if the burning is entirely accidental, like a gust of wind that blows a couple of notes into a family barbeque that you were recording at the time. and good luck proving that the currency on the tape is legal tender, because you might as well have put counterfeit money on the picknick table for similar fraud reasons.

Comment: @JacobKrall So either the money is real and you showed that it's real (which is impossible on camera) in which case there's probable cause that it's been staged and thus a crime. OR the money is real, but you didn't show it, in which case you can't prove it's real. OR it's fake, but you pretended it's real, in which case you're counterfeiting and defrauding, while recording your own evidence.